# For any propostional sentences $a,b,c$, if $a\models (b\wedge c)$, then $a\models b$ and $a\models c$

Tags: logic, model-theory

I'm having a hard time dealing with the $\models$ symbol. I don't really know how to reason through or manipulate these equations to prove why or why not the result holds. Another similar question is:

For any propostional sentences $a,b,c$, if $a\models (b\vee c)$, then $a\models b$ and $a\models c$.

Help on either of these would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The title of your question says $\land$, but the body of your question says $\lor$. I think you mean $\land$, but can you please fix one or the other?

Comment: @MJD The question in the title and the question posted in the body are two similar, but different questions. I added the second one because I thought that an explanation of both would help me understand $\models$ better.

Comment: I see, thanks.  Does your book have a definition of $\vDash$?  It doesn't always mean the same thing.

Comment: Yes. It says: $\alpha \models \beta$ if and only if, in every model in which $\alpha$ is true, $\beta$ is also true. That is, $\alpha \models \beta \leftrightarrow M(\alpha) \subseteq M(\beta)$.

Comment: Are you asking about how to reason about such statements (conceptually understanding why they are or are not true), or are you asking about how to prove such statements (in which case you need formal definitions of everything) ?

Comment: @DanielV The exam which these questions came from had them as "true/false with reason." It would be helpful to have a little bit of both, if that's not asking for too much. But, I think a conceptual understanding will help me prove them much more easily.

Comment: @Carley I'm afraid this question is really not appropriate for this site.  You seem to be basically asking for lectures on the subject rather than asking an answerable question.  Perhaps you could change your question to one that explicitly asks for introductory resources on model theory.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding :

> if $a \vDash (b∨c)$, then $a \vDash b$ and $a \vDash c$.

We have that : $a \vDash (b∨c)$ means that for every *valuation* $v$, if $v(a)=T$, then $v(b∨c)=T$.

But $v(b∨c)=T$ means that $v(b)=T$ **or** $v(c)=T$, but not necessarily both.

We can have $v(b)=T$ and $v(c)=F$ and this is enough for $v(b∨c)=T$.

So, it is **not** true that : if $a \vDash (b∨c)$, then $a \vDash b$ and $a \vDash c$.

---

For :

> if $a \vDash (b \land c)$, then $a \vDash b$ and $a \vDash c$,

we have that for every *valuation* $v$, if $v(a)=T$, then $v(b \land c)=T$, and this one means that $v(b)=T$ **and** $v(c)=T$.

Thus, in this case it is true that : if $a \vDash (b \land c)$, then $a \vDash b$ and $a \vDash c$.